# Using SMO to copy data only

Tags: c#, sql-server, smo

I'm trying to copy only the data by using SMO and I've got an error while processing the data

Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.TransferException: An error occurred while transferring data. See the inner exception for details.
---> System.InvalidOperationException: **The locale id '1033' of the source column 'ID' and the locale id '1036' of the destination column 'ID' do not match.**
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.AnalyzeTargetAndCreateUpdateBulkCommand(BulkCopySimpleResultSet internalResults)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerInternalRestContinuedAsync(BulkCopySimpleResultSet internalResults, CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerInternalRestAsync(CancellationToken cts, TaskCompletionSource`1 source)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerInternalAsync(CancellationToken ctoken)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteRowSourceToServerAsync(Int32 columnCount, CancellationToken ctoken)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(DbDataReader reader)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Transfer.SqlBulkCopyData(SqlConnection sourceConnection, SqlConnection destinationConnection, TransferWriter writer, SqlTransaction transaction)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Transfer.TransferData()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Transfer.TransferData()
at AtlasCLI.Commands.CopyDataCommand.CopyAllTablesData(CatalogSourceEndpoint source, CatalogDestinationEndpoint destination) in D:\Source\atlas-cli\src\Commands\CopyDataCommand.cs:line 114

you can find my setting here:

```
            var transfer = new Transfer(sourceServer.Databases[sourceConnection.Database])
            {
                Options =
                {
                    WithDependencies = true,
                    ContinueScriptingOnError = true,
                    AllowSystemObjects = true,
                    Indexes = true,
                    IncludeIfNotExists = true,
                    DriAll = true,
                    SchemaQualify = true,
                    ScriptSchema = false,
                    ScriptData = true
                },
                DestinationDatabase = destinationConnection.Database,
                DestinationServer = destinationServer.Name,
                DestinationLoginSecure = true,
                CopySchema = false,
                CopyData = true
        };

            transfer.DataTransferEvent += DataTransferEvent_Handler;
            transfer.DiscoveryProgress += DiscoveryProgress_Handler;
            transfer.ScriptingProgress += ScriptingProgressReport_Handler;
            transfer.ScriptingError += ScriptingErrorReport_Handler;
            transfer.TransferData();
```

Comment: Make sure your target database did not inherit a default locale id that you did not expect.  If this locale change problem is unexpected you could be inheriting a default that you did not expect.  A default cold be kicking in because you did not explicitly set a locale id.

Comment: Scripting the Table DDL file out from each DB could reveal a setting you did not expect related to locale and collations

Comment: @SqlSurfer How can I check the DB locale?

Comment: @SqlSurfer my source an target Collation values are different.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to change the destination database collation.

```
ALTER DATABASE [mydatabase] 
SET   SINGLE_USER
WITH  ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
Go
ALTER DATABASE [mydatabase] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI
Go
ALTER DATABASE [mydatabase] 
SET   MULTI_USER
```